# Convert datagrid selected item to my object type

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to delete the selected entity in DataGrid from my database.

```
using (var db = new MonitoringSystemContext())
{
    IT_Service selectedService = (IT_Service)ItServiceDataGrid.SelectedItem;            
    try
    {
        db.IT_Service.Remove(selectedService);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        UpdateDataGrids();
    }                
}
```

But I get an error of type 'System.InvalidCastException':

> Unable to cast object of type `<>f__AnonymousType1'3[System.Int32,System.String,System.String]` to type `DAL.Entity.IT_Service`.

Help me please with this error. Thanks for any answers

**UPD:** Datasource:

```
var GetServices = from s in _context.IT_Service
                  join cat in _context.IT_Service_Category
                  on s.IT_Service_CategoryIT_Service_Category_ID equals cat.IT_Service_Category_ID
                  select new { 
                      s.Service_ID,
                      s.Service_Name,
                      cat.IT_Service_Category_Name };
var resultServices = GetServices.ToList();
ItServiceDataGrid.ItemsSource = resultServices;
```

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the datasource ? It seems to be a problem in the datasource type.

Comment: @user3185569 of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Data source "resultServices" is not of type `IT_Service`, it is an `anonymous type` and it can't be converted into `IT_Service`

One option is to read the **ID** from the grid, then delete the element using the ID from the database.

Try this: **(Note that using dynamic in your case is not a good Practice)**

```
using (var db = new MonitoringSystemContext())
            {
                dynamic selectedService = ItServiceDataGrid.SelectedItem;            
                try
                {
                    int ID = selectedService.Service_ID;
                    var deletedService = db.IT_Service.FirstOrDefault(s=> s.Service_ID == ID);
                    if(deletedService != null)
                    {
                    db.IT_Service.Remove(deletedService);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                   }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    UpdateDataGrids();
                }                
            }
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the type of `IT_Service` instead `anonymous type`?

Comment: You can't, unless you change your datasource to type IT_Service, or try the solution i just edited using dynamic types.

Comment: Your solution does not work. On `(s => s.Service_ID == selectedService.Service_ID)` get an error: `an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.`

Comment: Thank you! Last question: Why do you use `dynamic` type instead `var` for example?

Comment: var just hides the type and let the compiler infer it. Dynamic is used in interop (Reading from Excel cells, communicate with languages like javascript, python). Dynamic is not really a good practice in your case, it is a hack here and not the best way to do it. Read more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx